# updating kubernetes deployment image doesn't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes

I updated the image used after making a new version of my app, I used the command:

```
kubectl set image deployment/flaskapp flaskapp=username/flaskapp:5 --record
```

In my first deployment yml file, I used the same name for the deployment, template and containers. Here is the description of the new pod:

```
  Normal  Pulling    32m   kubelet, ip-192-168-59-27.us-west-2.compute.internal  Pulling image "scientronic92/flaskapp:5"
  Normal  Pulled     32m   kubelet, ip-192-168-59-27.us-west-2.compute.internal  Successfully pulled image "scientronic92/flaskapp:5"
  Normal  Created    32m   kubelet, ip-192-168-59-27.us-west-2.compute.internal  Created container flaskapp
  Normal  Started    32m   kubelet, ip-192-168-59-27.us-west-2.compute.internal  Started container flaskapp
```

I am using aws loadbalancer, and when I curl the url or using my browser it shows me the same old result.

Note that I tested the new uploaded docker image locally and it worked fine.

Comment: Are you sure you `docker push`ed the right image?  Do you have some other mechanism that's overwriting the code in the container?  Or is your browser presenting a cached page?  A [mcve] showing how to cause this would be helpful; based only on the commands and output you've shown, it looks like it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in tagging and uploading docker image!

I was using:

```
docker tag flaskapp:4.0 scientronic92/flaskapp:5
```

instead of:

```
docker tag flaskapp:5.0 scientronic92/flaskapp:5
```

Comment: Could you edit answer and provide exact steps? It was typo in command? It might be helpful for other users.